# How to prevent "a" styling from applying to a link?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a banner for my site without using an image.  However, that banner is also a link.

Is there a way for me to override the use of the "a" (link) CSS styling from my div?

Assume the CSS looks like this:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #176093;
}

#logo {
    color: red;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

In other words, I'd like the CSS definitions for #logo to override the definitions for links.

Comment: Have you tried this: `#logo a { color: red; }`?

Comment: if `#logo` is a `div`, you can write your CSS like this: `#logo a { ... }`

Comment: You people are the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to answer:

Using this, you can specify styles within a given container:

```
#logo a {
    color: red;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to apply your styles to the anchor within the div `#logo`, you have to use a selector like this:

```css
#logo a { 
    color: red;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is like this;

```
<div id="logo"><a href="#">Banner Text</a></div>
```

then use CSS

```
#logo a:link, #logo a:visited{color:#176093;}
```

If HTML is like this

```
<a id="logo" href="#">Banner Text</a>
```

Then use CSS

```
#logo:link, #logo:visited{color:#176093;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the specificity of your selectors `:link` and `:visited`, you should override those as well:

```
#logo {
    font-size: 48px;
}

#logo:link, #logo:visited {
    color: red;
}
```